# Why does my data-binding with EditText not work?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have this class which I use for Room:

```
data class Piece(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    var title: String
)
```

Then I have a form class, which simply holds string values which I want to be shown in `EditText`.

```
class CreateEditPieceForm {
    var title: String = ""
}
```

My ViewModel holds instances of these classes:

```
class EditPieceViewModel(...) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val piece : LiveData<Piece?> = database.getMyPiece() // valid Piece with title set
    val form = CreateEditPieceForm()
}
```

In my fragment I observe the piece:

```
viewModel.piece.observe(this, Observer {piece ->
   piece?.let {
       viewModel.updateInputValues(piece)
    }
})
```

updateInputValues function in the ViewModel simply sets values in the form:

```
   fun updateInputValues(piece: Piece) {
        Log.d("mylog", "value: " + piece.title) // logs correct value
        form.title = piece.title // setting this does not change EditText
   }
```

And finally, in my layout, I try to use data binding to show the text from form.title in EditText:

```
<data>

  <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.tutorial.createedit.CreateEditPieceViewModel" />

</data>

<!-- ... -->

  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_title"
            <!-- ... -->
            android:inputType="text"

            android:text="@={viewModel.form.title}" />
```

When I open the Screen with this fragment, EditText is empty. I know that the query for piece title is correct, because I log it before I set EditText's text attribute.

When I type something in the empty field, value of `viewModel.form.title` is being set with that value.

Why does it not set right at the beginning?

Comment: `.observe(this` should probably use `viewLifecycleOwner`

Comment: I think this would also work if you make `CreateEditPieceForm` do `extends BaseObservable`. Then you don't have to make `viewModel` itself observable. But you can also use `ObservableField<String>` instead of `String`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what is the difference if I use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this`?

Comment: Depends on where you wrote your `observe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. I still do not fully understand the Databinding library, so any advice to improve the code is welcomed!

I changed my ViewModel to implement Observable and added some methods to it:

```
// Make sure to import the correct Observable interface
import androidx.databinding.Observable
// ...

class EditPieceViewModel(...) : AndroidViewModel(application), Observable {

   // ...

   // New getter and setter methods for my title field:

    @Bindable
    fun getTitle() : String {
        return form.title
    }

    fun setTitle(value: String) {
        if(form.title != value) {
            form.title = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title) // This line is important for EditText' value to update
        }
    }


   // New methods added for Observable:

    override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(
        callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback) {
        callbacks.add(callback)
    }

    override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(
        callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback) {
        callbacks.remove(callback)
    }

    /**
     * Notifies observers that a specific property has changed. The getter for the
     * property that changes should be marked with the @Bindable annotation to
     * generate a field in the BR class to be used as the fieldId parameter.
     *
     * @param fieldId The generated BR id for the Bindable field.
     */
    fun notifyPropertyChanged(fieldId: Int) {
        callbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, null)
    }

}
```

In layout xml I changed title to observe viewModel.title instead of viewModel.form.title:

```
        <EditText
            // ...
            android:text="@={viewModel.title}" />
```

Finally in updateInputValues I call my custom setter:

```
fun updateInputValues(piece: Piece) {
        setTitle(piece.title)
}
```

Comment: That's great! As you probably found out, the EditText was not updated because neither `form` nor your viewmodel were Observable to perform a property change through `notifyCallbacks`.  

To improve the code I'd make `form` a `Piece` object instead, use custom get/set on the title field and hide `Observable` details in a [BaseObservableViewModel](https://medium.com/mindorks/making-viewmodel-observable-6a5398fdb0c8).

Comment: Hmm. I could have sworn 2-way data binding was working without doing all this crap. But this is also bad because you're being forced to tightly couple your business models with something else. Imagine you want to have a core library that will be used by different application components. Also, where is ```callbacks``` defined at/coming from?

Answer (score 1):

[Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) is not to be confused with 
[View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Like in the guide, make EditPieceViewModel implement Observable and make `form.title` @Bindable.

Comment: Ok, so I did, but it still does not update the text of EditText in the beginning. The getter with @Bindable annotation is just not being called when I change `form.title`

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to get it work now, I will post my code shortly!